# SQL Server: Take the contents of a table as a backup to be used in other table

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have the following situation:

In my production DB, i want to save the contents of a table to my local DB copy.

Example:

In my production DB `DB_PRODUCTION`: i have the table `Company` with all the live data.

What I want to do is to copy the contents of the `Company` table into the `Company` Table of my test environment (that is located on a local server).

How can I do this without taking a complete backup of the `DB_PRODUCTION` database?

What I wanted to do is to perform a `SELECT * FROM Company`  query on the production DB, save the result to .csv and import it in my `DB_TEST` database.

But is this even supported/Possible?

The version is SQL Server 2013 (Production) and SQL Server 2016 (Test)

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click on your source database and choose "Export..." from the context menu. The wizard will guide you through the process where you can select the desired source and target table(s) and options. If you want to maintain identity column values, make sure you activate this option.

The whole process also works the same way if you choose "Import..." on your target database.

As a bonus, you can opt to save the configuration for later re-use.